# how to drive a div's position with a browser scrollbar (as shown in Paranorman website)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I'm trying to figure out how this was accomplished:

http://www.paranorman.com/

In this site, the browser window's scrollbar drives the scroll position of a DIV. However, the window has a scrollbar even if it fits entirely into your browser window.

I need to make a site with a container element that will be driven by a scrollbar, even though the site container will be a size that fits in most desktop browser windows without needing to be scrolled.

Comment: Hi, it probably uses one of these jquery parallax plugins: http://smashinghub.com/7-jquery-parallax-and-scrolling-effect-plugins.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done with trickery, where the body (or some other element) has a large size so as to get a scrollbar, and another element is placed with position fixed and height/width 100% in front of the scrolled element and takes up the entire screen, so the scrolled element is'nt visible. Then it's all about getting the scrollTop/Left values and moving elements inside the front fixed element according to how much the scrollbar is moved, making it look like it's being scrolled, when you're really moving stuff with javascript based on the scrollTop/Left values, and we call it, parallax. It all sounds harder then it really is.

Comment: Which is the element on the paranorman site which has a larger size? The body and html both have a width of 100%

Comment: They have a `#scene-nav-wrapper` that they use for the scrollbar, with transform 3D and some javascript to move stuff around the mentioned fixed element, called `#scene-wrapper` on the paraNorman site.